# Using reflection to get all classes of certain base type in dll

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a dll that contains a number of classes that all inherit from a CommandBase class. I'm trying to get instances of all of these classes (CommandA, CommandB, CommandC, etc...) using reflection in C# so that I can call a specific method on each one. Here is what I have so far:

```
//get assemblies in directory.
string folder = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/"), "bin");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.dll");
//load each assembly.
foreach (string file in files)
{
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
  if (assembly.FullName == "MyCommandProject")
  {
    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
      if (!type.IsClass || type.IsNotPublic) continue;
      if(type is CommandBase)
      {
        var command = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as CommandBase;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm having 2 issues. The 1st issue is that the line "if(type is CommandBase") gives the following warning:

**The given expression is never of the provided type CommandBase.**

The 2nd issue is that I can't figure out how to get an instance of the actual object (CommandA, CommandB, etc...), just converting it to CommandBase isn't enough.

Comment: Your last line doesn't create properly the instance ?
`With Activator.CreateInstance()`, you should have an instance of CommandA, CommandB... class (depending on `type`), no ?

Comment: Activation.CreateInstance() returns type object.

Comment: Yes but it returns an object of the type you provided. You can store it in a "object" var or a "CommandBase" var, it will still be a CommandA, CommandB, etc. instance. You can cast it later to it's "real" type.
I don't have a Visual Studio to check but I'm don't see what is the issue.

Comment: Maybe I see what you want but it's not possible. I think you expect the "var" to be of type CommandA, CommandB, etc. 
But var is just a simplified notation, it is not a "varying" type, when it'll be compiled, it will be replaced by a "static" type, in your case it will always be CommandBase. But this is just a container for your instance. As I said previously, the object "inside" is of type "CommandA", "CommandB"... It is just that it is stored in a more generic variable so you don't have access to each object specific members. Only to members inherited from parent.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the method I use to load up based on an interface.

```
private static List<T> GetInstances<T>()
{
        return (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (T)) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select (T) Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
}
```

And here's the same function that pulls back based on base class.

```
private static IList<T> GetInstances<T>()
{
        return (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                       where t.BaseType == (typeof(T)) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                       select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToList();
}
```

Of course it would need to be modified slightly to point at the reference you're loading.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it only returns the CommandBase class, not classes that inherit from it. Also, if I call it like "GetInstances<CommandBase>()", then it gives me a list of CommandBase objects, not the objects I need - CommandA, CommandB, etc.. It sounds like I need to use interfaces to get this to work.

Comment: Added a second function for you to use for your CommandBase class.  You should retrieve a list of instance of classes that inherit from CommandBase. Works when I throw it into a simple snippet test.

Comment: I ended up switching to using interfaces and used your first code example, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You must change

```
if(type is CommandBase)
```

to

```
if(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CommandBase)))
```

If the IsSubclassOf is the converse of IsAssignableFrom. That is, if t1.IsSubclassOf(t2) is true, then t2.IsAssignableFrom(t1) is also true.

Comment: That is, except for my answer, which was correct from the beginning. :), but I'm giving you a +1 for being right and because I've just never noticed the IsSubclassOf method, since I just use IsAssignableFrom.

Answer (score 8):

Change `type is CommandBase` to `typeof(CommandBase).IsAssignableFrom(type)`

Comment: +1 I didnt see your result when I was typing, however this msdn says "If the IsSubclassOf is the converse of IsAssignableFrom. That is, if t1.IsSubclassOf(t2) is true, then t2.IsAssignableFrom(t1) is also true." so we both are equally right, I was pointing towards answers of is and == answers.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `type` variable is a `Type`, not a `CommandBase`.

You want

```
if(type == typeof(CommandBase))
```

(Thanks Greg for the correction)

Comment: It ended up being "==" instead of "is" but yeah that worked, thanks. Any advice on my 2nd issue?

Comment: I can tell you it's getting casted as a CommandBase because, well, you're casting it to one, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to cast it to the higher class, since you're getting into a loss of type safety at that point. Usually with something like this, you want to have an interface where you can call the same functions in all of the derived classes.

Comment: I doubt it will even compile because "Is" expects class name, not type.

Comment: Fixed the is -> == in the answer.