# Get instance of class and methos using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using reflection to get all classes of certain base type in dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353699/using-reflection-to-get-all-classes-of-certain-base-type-in-dll)

I use Unity to call methods in my classes.
My help class for this looks like this.

```
protected T Using<T>() where T : class
{
   var handler = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>();
   if (handler == null)
   {
      throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to resolve type with service locator");
   }
   return handler;
}
```

To call a method in a class i use this code

```
Using<FooService>().Get(parameter);
```

But can i use reflection to get class and method?

Example

```
string className = "FooService";
string methodName = "Get";
string parameterName = "Parameter"

Using<className>().methodName(parameterName)
```

Comment: What would `parameterName` be? Could you make a more detailed example?

Comment: Are you looking for `Type.GetMethod()`, `Type.GetMember()`, or `Type.GetProperty()` by any chance?