# Detect Right Click On Every PictureBox On The Form

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to detect a right click on any `PictureBox` in the form. I have already set up the right click function for one `PictureBox`. This is fine but I would like one event that will fire for all right clicks on `PictureBoxes` on the form.

This right click even will need to know the `PictureBox` name because the context menu will be different for some of the `PictureBoxes`.

Here is the code I have for the right click event for one `PictureBox`.

```
private void DesktopIcon1Icon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Right:
        {
            DesktopIconRightclick.Show(this, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I need to adapt this code to fire if any `PictureBox` is right clicked.

**Example Update**

```
if (pic = DesktopIcon2)
{
    openToolStripMenuItem.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one event that will fire for all right clicks on `PictureBoxes` like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox_MouseClick;
    pictureBox2.MouseClick += pictureBox_MouseClick;
}
```

Then you can use `Sender` to find `PictureBox`'s `Name` like this:

```
private void pictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var pic = (sender as PictureBox).Name;//pic is the Name of the PictureBox that is clicked
    switch (e.Button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Right:
        {
            MessageBox.Show(pic);//Just for example
            DesktopIconRightclick.Show(this, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got it working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using reflection to find all PictureBox instances.
Check [GetTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx) as a starting point.

Check this SO for implementation example:
[Using reflection to get all classes of certain base type in dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353699/using-reflection-to-get-all-classes-of-certain-base-type-in-dll)

Comment: This looks good, not too sure if it would be suitable for my needs. But thanks.

Comment: No need for reflection I think, you can use the Controls property of the form and `is PictureBox` operator on every control. You may need to recurse on children controls having a Controls as well