# How do I check which button is being clicked? Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, button

I'm working with 70 buttons in my application, so I was thinking that instead of making different button1_Click, button2_Click... button70_Click events, I would just make one. The problem is that I don't know how to check what is the current button that is being clicked, since whenever I click a button I want its color to change.

Comment: You can retrieve it by casting the `sender` argument of the event handler to Button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Right Click On Every PictureBox On The Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528548/detect-right-click-on-every-picturebox-on-the-form)

Comment: @KooKiz but in the event I want to change the BackColor of the clicked button to green. how do i know its name in order to change its color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the `sender` parameter of your event handler to `Button`

```
Button ClickedButton = (Button)sender;
```

That is the button that raised the event.

You would use it in the handler you assign to each button's click event, e.g.

```
public form1() 
{
        //You probably do this in a loop over all your buttons
        button1.Click += MyButtonClickHandler;
}

private void MyButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button ClickedButton = (Button)sender;
    ClickedButton.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Where do I insert this line? Right before the button clicking event?

Comment: Oh, I understood! Sorry for taking me so long.