# Memory game, PictureBox im1 = sender as PictureBox; loses it's address

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a basic memory game for now in C#, I'm using sender as `PictureBox` to determine min which picture  box is selected.After that I have to check if the tags are equal, and here `im2` and `im1` loses its address. How can I save the addresses so they don't get loss?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int k = 1;
    PictureBox im1, im2;
    int r1, r2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (k == 1)
        {
            PictureBox im1 = sender as PictureBox;`enter code here`
            r1 = Convert.ToInt16(im1.Tag);
            string s = "slike\\sl";
            s = s + r1.ToString() + ".jpg";
            Image i = Image.FromFile(@s);
            im1.Image = i;
            k = 2;


        }
        else
        {
            PictureBox im2 = sender as PictureBox;
            r2 = Convert.ToInt16(im2.Tag);
            string s = "slike\\sl";
            s = s + r2.ToString() + ".jpg";
            Image i = Image.FromFile(@s);
            im2.Image = i;
            k = 0;
        }
        if(k==0) {
            if (r1 == r2)
            {
                Image i = Image.FromFile(@"slike\\pogodjeno.jpg");
                im1.Image = i;
                im2.Image = i;
                im1.Enabled = false;
                im2.Enabled = false;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Image i = Image.FromFile(@"slike\\pozadina.jpg");
                im1.Image = i;
                im2.Image = i;
                r1 = 0;
                r2 = 0;
                k = 1;
            }

        }

     }

      private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }
     }
}
```

Comment: Just cut your code in the `Click` method and paste it in the shared click event. Example http://stackoverflow.com/a/35528628/2946329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem right:

```
PictureBox im1, im2;
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        PictureBox im1 = sender as PictureBox;`enter code here`
```

You probably want this:

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        im1 = sender as PictureBox;`enter code here`
```